# Monotonically increasing fields in composite indexes

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Suppose I have a Datastore kind with two properties listed below and an extremely high insert rate overall (but low insertion rate for individual values of `random_key`):

1. `random_key` - a uniformly distributed large number
2. `time` - a monotonically increasing timestamp indicating the insertion time of an entity

I'm primarily concerned with queries on the composite index `(random_key ASC, time DESC)` and I don't care about queries on just the `time` field.

**Problem:**  But according to the datastore documentation, creating this composite index requires that I not exclude the `random_key` and `time` fields from auto-indexing. According to the best practices, indexing on `time` will lead to the hotspoting issue as it is monotonically increasing.

Other questions such as [Google datastore - index a date created field without having a hotspot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131787/google-datastore-index-a-date-created-field-without-having-a-hotspot) recommend prepending a random value to the timestamp to shard the data. But I'd like to try and have a clean approach that uses a more meaningful value in the other separate property `random_key`

**Question:**
What are my options for maintaining the composite index on both fields without having any of the issues related to the auto-index on `time` alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding/ignoring the hot-spotting issue on auto-indexing on `time` alone doesn't really change/improve things for the composite index: you're still having the problem of updating an index (a composite one, but that doesn't really make a difference) with a monothonically increasing property value, which is still subject to the hot-spotting issue.

That's because the underlying fundamental root cause of the hot-spotting issue, graphically illustrated in [App Engine datastore tip: monotonically increasing values are bad](https://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/), is the number of worker threads that the indexing update workload can be distributed to:

- with monothonically changing property values consecutive index updates requests tend to keep hitting the same worker thread  which can only perform them in a serialized manner - the hotspot
- with random/uniformly distributed property values consecutive indexing update requests can be statistically distributed to multiple workers to be executed in parallel. This is really what sharding is doing for monothonically changing properties as well.

The answer to the question you referenced applies in the composite index case equally well: you can use sharding for `time` if have an update rate above the mentioned tipping point of 500 writes/sec.

But sharding complicates your app: you'd need multiple queries and client-side merging of the results. If your `random_key` is indeed more meaningful you *might* find it more attractive instead to:

- keep `time` unindexed (thus avoiding hot-spotting alltogether)
- only query by `random_key` (which doesn't require a composite index) and simply handle the `time` filtering via client side processing (which *might* be less processing than combining results from sharded queries).